# Unable to catch error , when thrown from called function in Typescript

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to use try and catch in Ionic framework with Typescript.
I tried to call throw from the called function. (Please refer Code snippet)

```js
function foo() {
    try {
        bar();
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert(e);
    }
}

function bar() {
    foo2();
}

function foo2() {
    throw "Error here";
}
```

I expect the error should be caught at foo() in catch Block and should show in alert instead of saying Runtime error and stack trace.

Comment: What's the exact error? I just tried it and it worked.

Comment: Do you get the alert ?

Comment: Yes. Granted, I ran it in the Chrome console, not in the same environment as you, but the code is sound at least.

Comment: It works, you can check it by running it in the playground: https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIgxKAJwE8d9CqAjAQ2MwG5KCBfFxCWqCAC0TQBTLHipUICAM5wANoIB0MuAHMhGZmMK05xKGo2F27XKEiwEiOgxEcUcAExNcx09HhI7jm1Si9icAHdEACIAUWJ-YkReQWJBYOYXVEwgA

Comment: I get like this in console (Runtime Error) -
core.es5.js:1020 ERROR Error: Failure
    at SafeSubscriber._next (transdashboarddetail.ts:265)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:242)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:189)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:129)
    at CatchSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
    at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:93)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.es5.js:1226)